# How to erase certain characters in a string using a for loop?

Tags: java, string, methods, charat

I'm trying to write a function that takes a `String` parameter str. It returns a new version where all the "x" characters have been removed. Except an "x" at the very start or end of str should not be removed. I can only use loops for this problem, not `StringBuilder` or `.replace()` method.

I'm not sure how to erase a character at a certain string position. So far this is the code I have, any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
public String stringX(String str)
{
    String result = str;
    int len = str.length() - 1;


    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
    {
        char letter = str.charAt(i);
        if (letter == 'x' && ((i != 0) && (i != len)))
        {

        } 
    }

    return result; 
}
```

Comment: *Except an "x" at the very start **or** end of str should not be removed* , so when it suppose to remove first and when it suppose to remove end ???

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a character from a String because the String is immutable (can't be changed). If you want to read a little bit more about this [check the documentation out here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and read that introductory information.

Basically, this means you need to create a new String that has all the characters you do want.

What you could do is turn your input into a `char[]` and loop through with your current for loop. When you find a character that isn't an x you can append it to an empty String for output.

```
public String stringX(String str)
  {
  char[] c = str.toCharArray();
  String result = "";
  int len = str.length() - 1;

  for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
  {
    char letter = c[i];
    if (!(letter == 'x' && ((i != 0) && (i != len))))
    {
      result += letter;
    } 
  }

  return result; 
}
```

This would require changing very little of the code you have, while still offering the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String stringX(String str) {
 String a = "";
  if(str.length() > 2){
   String front = str.substring(0,1), 
    back = str.substring(str.length()-1),
     middle = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
      for(int i = 0; i < middle.length(); i++){
       if(middle.charAt(i) != 'x') a += middle.charAt(i);
      }
      return front + a + back;
  }
 return str;
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -1):

I have done some modification in your code :

```
String result = "";
int len = str.length() - 1;

for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
{
    char letter = str.charAt(i);
     if (letter == 'x' && ((i == 0) || (i == len))) {
        result += String.valueOf(letter);
    }        
    else if(letter != 'x'){
        result += String.valueOf(letter);
    }    
}
```

Comment: @ETR009 this modification will be give you the desired result.

Comment: can you test for `xxy` ?

Comment: @Ravi its working fine for input xxy and gives xy as output.

Comment: Thank you for your input, it helped a lot.